# Why tbody will be added automatically by browser?

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

In my html, one extra `<TR>` and `<TD>` is added into `table` without close element by mistake.

```
<TABLE border=\"1\" summary=\"\" width=\"100%%\">
<CAPTION><EM>Statistics</EM></CAPTION><TR><TD>
<COLGROUP span=\"4\" ALIGN=\"center\"></COLGROUP>
```

Test it in Chrome, `TBODY` is added automatically, and also with close element.

[image]

But in IE, `TBODY` will be added automatically, but without close element.

[image]

IMO, since the HTML is incorrect, why browser will correct them by adding extra `tbody`?

Comment: I think the Chrome and IE DOMs you're looking at there are actually the same, they're just displayed slightly differently.

Answer (score 2):

The browser has to correct the code in order to create a DOM hieararchy from it.

The code is incorrect, but how much depends on the DOCTYPE that you are using. There is no need to specify the `tbody` element, it's added automatically. In HTML (but not XHTML) it's allowed to leave `tr` and `td` elements without a closing tag. The `table` tag should have a closing tag, though.

The two browsers produce the same result, the difference is that IE is just not showing any closing tags for the elements. Once the code is parsed into elements, there are actually no opening tags and closing tags, there are only elements. The developers of Chrome just chose to show the element as an opening tag and a closing tag, presumably so that it would look more like HTML code.

Comment: Browser behavior does not depend on DOCTYPE, but it depends on serialization mode (HTML vs. XHTML). If the document is served with an XHTML content type and therefore parsed as XHTML, `tr` is allowed as a child of `table`, so no `tbody` element is added. In HTML mode, it’s different: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#element-restrictions